# How to add the summation of two binomial coefficients?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, binomial-coefficients

I am asked to prove that where *n* is an even integer,$$\displaystyle\sum_{k = 0}^{n/2}\dbinom{n}{2k} = \sum_{\substack{k = 1 \\}}^{n/2}\dbinom{n}{2k-1}$$

or, in other words:
$$\displaystyle\sum_{k = 0}^{n/2}\dbinom{n}{2k} - \sum_{\substack{k = 1 \\}}^{n/2}\dbinom{n}{2k-1}=0$$

I tested it with different values for n, and it all makes sense. However, I cannot figure out mathematical reasoning for why this is true. Thus, I can't figure out the steps to take for a proper proof. I thought I could index-shift the second summation:

$$\displaystyle\sum_{k = 0}^{n/2}\dbinom{n}{2k} - \sum_{\substack{k = 0 \\}}^{n/2}\dbinom{n}{2k+1}=0$$

But I don't know where to go from there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> We obtain for even integer $n>0$
>   \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{\sum_{k=0}^{n/2}}&\color{blue}{\binom{n}{2k}-\sum_{k=1}^{n/2}\binom{n}{2k-1}}\tag{1}\\
> &=\sum_{{k=0}\atop{k\text{ even}}}^{n}\binom{n}{k}-\sum_{{k=0}\atop{k\text{ odd}}}^{n}\binom{n}{k}\tag{2}\\
> &=\sum_{k=0}^n(-1)^k\binom{n}{k}\tag{3}\\
> &=(1-1)^n\tag{4}\\
> &\color{blue}{=0}
> \end{align*}

*Comment:*

- In (1) we add binomial coefficients $\binom{n}{2k}$ with even lower part and subtract the binomial coefficients $\binom{n}{2k-1}$ with odd lower part.
- In (2) we not the left-hand sum of (1) adds up $\binom{n}{0}+\binom{n}{2}+\binom{n}{6}+\cdots$ while the right-hand sum in (1) subtracts $\binom{n}{1}+\binom{n}{3}+\binom{n}{5}+\cdots$.
- In (3) we do the same as in (2).
- In (4) we apply the *[binomial theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem)*.

Comment: Thank you! Can you elaborate what happens between (1) and (2)? I'm not sure how two summations are combined like that when they have a different starting k.

Comment: @SumikoH What happens is that (1) is $$\left[\binom n0+\binom n2+\binom n4+\cdots+\binom nn\right]-\left[\binom n1+\binom n3+\cdots+\binom n{n-1}\right]$$ and (2) is $$\binom n0-\binom n1+\binom n2-\binom n3+\cdots-\binom n{n-1}+\binom nn.$$

Comment: @SumikoH: I've added an intermediate step which might be helpful.

Comment: @SumikoH By even integer you must mean even *positive* integer since the equality fails when $n=0.$ Alternatively, change the right hand side from $0$ to $0^0$ and then it holds for even $n\ge0.$

Comment: @bof: Good point. This should be stated more precisely. ($0^0$ should also be defined, since it's definition is not standard; although most commonly equal to $1$ within combinatorics).

Comment: @bof: Typo corrected. Thanks.